# Edit file in vim without modifying owner

Tags: vim, permissions, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, ownership

I have a set of files in a directory `/etc/tomcat/conf` that are owned by user `tomcat` and group `www`.

When I use vim to edit a file in that directory, the ownership of that file changes to my user/group.

How can I update the file without modifying the owner?

I'm running CentOS 7.2 with:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 10 2014 06:55:55)
```

Included patches: 1-160

Comment: Instead of overwriting a file, Vim creates a new file, removes the old, and moves the new one into its place. This behavior can't be changed, as far as I know, and will always result in an ownership change in situations like this.

Comment: @Heptite I was not aware of that.  Is that also the case with other editors, like `nano`?  Or would `nano` modify the existing file without changing the owner?

Comment: OK, I just tested `nano` and it does not suffer from the same issue.  This is very disappointing as I was just starting to like `vim`

Comment: Haven't tried it but, you could get the owner and group with ```stat```. Might work if you wrote a little script that will get this and save to a register and call ```chown``` after ```:w```.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from your question, but I assume that you have write permissions in the `/etc/tomcat/conf` directory and also write permissions on all the files within the `/etc/tomcat/conf` directory. If that is the case, vim should actually just leave the file owner unchanged, unless you have some non-default settings in your .vimrc.

Try executing `:set backupcopy` to see the value of the `backupcopy` variable. If it's set to `no` that's bad, because vim will rename the file and write a new one (see `:help backupcopy`).

If you *don't* have write permissions in the `/etc/tomcat/conf` directory, vim should warn you pretty clearly that it's unable to write the file and you'll only be able to do so with `:w!`. Also, I would be surprised if nano still worked if that were the case, since as far as I know, nano will be completely unable to write in that case.

Comment: I have write permission since my user is a member of the `www` group.